Isomorphism between Groupring on complex numbers and direct sum of irreducible representations
For a group G we get irreducible representations $\phi:G \rightarrow GL(V_i)$. I want to see why $ \mathbb{C}G \cong \bigoplus\limits_{i=1,...,r}End(V_i)$. I have been looking at the proof of Proposition 3.29 in "Representation theory" by W. Fulton und J. Harris. I understand that since G is part of the group ring  you can extend the irreducible representations of G to $\mathbb{C}G$ via linearity and you end up with a homomorphism. I'm just not really sure how they arrive at this map being injective and both sets having the same dimension. I have been working through a different text and only looked at the book in question for this one specific proof so I feel a bit lost here. Can someone perhaps explain their reasoning (or alternatively provide their own) in a bit more detail?

This follows from Maschke's theorem together with the Artin-Wedderburn theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%E2%80%93Artin_theorem
